# My android emulator doesn't show updates to my application?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

New changes in my code are not reflected to the android emulator. Im building a cross-platform app using xamarin forms and xamarin studio.Even running the project on visual studio doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: This is a general question, and not related to programming

Comment: Do the changes show up on the iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Some troubleshooting tips..

1 - First, delete the app from the Emulator, and then close the emulator.

2 - Navigate to your project folder, find the android project,  and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders.

3 - Perform a Clean, and then Rebuild of your project. You can now try launching the emulator again

The key point here is deleting the bin and obj files. When xamarin builds, it builds the resources and compiled code to these folders. Deleting them will mean it has to be regenerated again, so it will generate a new copy - which means the next build may take slightly longer, but it will be a fresh copy of all the files needed.

Make sure to have deleted the app on the phone so as to get a fresh copy there too. (in extreme cases, you can also reset the emulator somewhere in the AVD settings)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried deleting the app on the emulator and then reinstalling again? If that's not enough, sometimes you have to delete the app explicit in the app list in settings (deleting all data by app and then deinstall)

When the app crashes on Android emulator sometimes it doesn't update, even with restarting by Visual Studio.